# Firestore: Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query some documents from firestore and my query is structured as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(POST_DB)
            .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
            .where(
              Filter.and(
                Filter.or(
                  Filter("field1", arrayContainsAny: someArrayValues),
                  Filter("field2", whereIn: someOtherArrayValues),
                ),
                Filter("field3", isNotEqualTo: someValue),
              ),
            );
```

This query seems to be failing for some reason. When I'm not using `isNotEqualTo` with `field3` and also removing `Filter.and` and only keeping `Filter.or`, the query seems to be working fine, but when using `isNotEqualTo`, the following error is happening:

[image]

Also, when using `isEqualTo` instead of `isNotEqualTo`, the query seems to be working fine. Any help will be appreciated.